# How to use java 8 source code for a project running on jre 6 server

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-8, compatibility

An old project has JRE 6 installed on servers. The project is a maven project, in parent pom project the version specified for the maven compiler (source and target are 6), i need to add a project that depends on that parent project and loads dependencies made by java 6, but i want to use Java 8 features in my new code. Is it possible? what i need to change without having problems for what is runing already on servers, and how i configure Eclipse for that purpose?

Comment: No it is not possible. JRE 6 will not run Java 8 code.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your answer

Comment: After more than a decade, it’s not bad to consider updating server software…

Comment: Holger i have already my own projects in a server which runs on the latest openjdk, but the owners of those projects are afraid of the new java style and get stuck in old java and they dont want to change their mind unfortunately.

Comment: So they are afraid of a style (which they don’t have to use) but not afraid of the security bugs in an ancient software that doesn’t receive updates? And, if you find a way to use Java 8 features in your code and bring that code into their JRE 6 server, wouldn’t that disprove their entire concept of mixing up coding style and runtime version?

Comment: They do not want to spend a cent on updating legacy projects that are used internally. They have projects with modern architecture and tools. It depends on project's owners.